# How can you use a symbol to reference an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I'm trying to convert a project I've written in Ruby to use Classes.

Block I'm currently using:

```
elements.each do |element, value|
    value /= 100
    total.push(value * price[element])
end
```

Full code:  https://gist.github.com/gbourdon/53d3d125b04a9394164daca01b657987

Hash structure:

```
price = {o: 0.30, c: 2.40, h: 12.00, etc.}
```

I need the symbol stored in the hash (For instance, :o) to be able to reference an object with the same name (For instance, the object o).

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Don't declare a heap of variables with names like `o`, instead orgnize those into a structure and keep them keyed. This will make looking them up *significantly* easier, and I think this jumble of variables is the source of your problems. `elements[:o]` is *way* easier than looking up variable `o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reworked, Ruby-ified version of your code that avoids the need to have those variables entirely. If you look at the operations here you don't care, particularly, what the element is, you only care about it's value and relative abundance per unit of weight.

A retooled Element class looks like this:

```
class Element
  attr_reader :symbol
  attr_reader :price
  attr_reader :amount

  def initialize(symbol, price, amount)
    # Cocerce both inputs into floats
    @symbol = symbol
    @price = price.to_f
    @amount = amount.to_f
  end
end
```

Now that contains information important to the element itself, like its symbol. Keeping the symbol some place like the variable name is actually quite annoying as variable names shouldn't have significant meaning like that, they should only be for readability.

Now you can define all of your elements in one shot, inside one container object:

```
ELEMENTS = [
  Element.new('O', 0.30, 0.65),
  Element.new('C', 2.40, 0.18),
  Element.new('H', 12, 0.10),
  Element.new('N', 0.40, 0.03),
  Element.new('Ca', 11, 0.015),
  Element.new('P', 4, 0.01),
  Element.new('K', 85, 0.0035),
  Element.new('S', 0.25, 0.0025),
  Element.new('Cl', 0.15, 0.0015),
  Element.new('Na', 7, 0.0015)
]
```

The resulting executable can be streamlined a bunch more, too, especially on the input conversion:

```
# Take input from the command-line to make re-running this easier
pounds = ARGV[0].to_i

# Quick conversion in one shot. Try and keep variables all lower_case
kg = pounds * 0.4536 * 1000
```

Now all you need to do is convert each element in that table into a net price based on the weight:

```
# Convert each element into its equivalent value by weight
total = ELEMENTS.map do |element|
  element.price * element.amount * kg
end.reduce(:+) # Added together
```

Where `reduce` here is a replacement for the unnecessary Array method. It does wha you need. Rails actually has a `sum` method which is even easier.

Then to present:

```
puts "You are worth: $#{(total / 100).round(2)}"
```

That's it.

With this new structure you could expand on the functionality to give a detailed breakdown of price by element if you wanted, all the information necessary is contained within that `element` object. That's why a more self-contained object design is better.

Comment: As I like to say: Ruby is an object-oriented language, not a hash-of-symbols-to-floats-oriented language, so use objects, not hashes-of-symbols-to-floats and everything will become much easier.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sometimes "dumb" data structures are good enough for the task at hand. Sometimes they need to be smarter in order to make extending them easier. It's not always a clear call. I'd still rather have a wonky, baroque data structure than some unstructured data like heaps of variables.